# Why FOUND_ROW() works without putting the function into SELECT statement?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Here is my code:

```
$query = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 1, id, name
                FROM users where id > ?";
$sth = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
$sth->execute([4]);
echo $total_num = $this->dbh->query('SELECT FOUND_ROWS()')->fetchColumn();
//=> 43
```

My code works as well and prints `43`.

---

My question is, why my code still works when I remove `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 1` from `SELECT` statement?

```
$query = "SELECT id, name
                FROM users where id > ?";
$sth = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
$sth->execute([4]);
echo $total_num = $this->dbh->query('SELECT FOUND_ROWS()')->fetchColumn();
//=> 43
```

See? It still prints `43`. So is putting `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 1` in the `SELECT` statement mandatory? Why should we put it there anyway?

Comment: Doesn't the documentation say that in the absence of the `SQL_CALC...` option that it just returns the count of rows from the last statement run (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows).

Comment: @NigelRen Ah, thank you .. And can you tell me what happens if one user on my website load a page *(which has a query)* and another user load another page *(which has `FOUND_ROW()`)*? What will be the result of `FOUND_ROW()`?

Comment: It's always specific to the connection